# Question on the convergence of a recursively defined sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I am trying to prove that the convergence of the following sequence.

> Consider a sequence $\{a_j\}$ defined by $a_1\in [-1/4,1/4]$ and $a_{j+1}=a_j ^{2}-\frac{1}{4},$ for all $j\geq1.$

Here's what I have gathered so far

> Given $a_1=a$, for some $a\in[-1/4,1/4]$, we have $a_2=a_1^2 -1/4=a^2 -1/4;\\ a_3 =a_2^2 - 1/4 = (a^2-1/4)^2-1/4;\\ a_4 = ((a^2-1/4)^2-1/4)^2-1/4; \\\ ... $

But I am stuck as to how I can use this information to prove that $\{a_j\}$ converges. Any hint/help will be very useful. Thanks.

Comment: Two straightforward tools at your disposal: monotone convergence theorem, and the (Banach) fixed point convergence theorem (consider the derivative).

Comment: not that important, but you should note that "recurrent" actually means something specific...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If $a_j$ converges to $L$ then $a_{j+1}$ converges to $L$ and $a_j^2$ converges to $L^2.$ So $L=L^2-1/4,$ implying $L=(1\pm \sqrt 2\,)/2.$
2. If $|a_j|\le 1/4$ then $|a_{j+1}|=|a_j^2-1/4|\le 1/4.$ And $|a_1|\le 1/4.$ So by induction, we have $|a_j|\le 1/4$ for all $j.$ So $a_j$ cannot converge to $(1+\sqrt 2\,)/2.$ So if the limit $L$ exists then $L=(1-\sqrt 2\,)/2.$
3. Let $L=(1-\sqrt 2\,)/2.$ Let $a_j=L+b_j.$  Then $$|b_{j+1}|=|a_{j+1}-L|=|a_j^2-1/4-L|=$$ $$=|(L+b_j)^2-1/4-L|=|(L^2-1/4-L)+2Lb_j+b_j^2|=$$ $$=|2Lb_j+b_j^2|=|b_j|\cdot |2L+b_j|.$$ Now $|2L+b_j|=|L+a_j| \le |L|+|a_j|\le |L|+1/4<1/2.$ So we have $$|b_{j+1}|=|b_j|\cdot |2L+b_j|\le |b_j|/2$$ which implies $b_j\to 0.$

Comment: If it is suspected that a sequence $a_j$ converges to a limit $L,$ it is often easier to prove that $a_j-L=b_j\to 0.$

Answer (score 0):

I am going to prove the convergence of the following sequence:

> Consider a sequence $\,\left\{a_j\right\}_{j\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathbb R\,$ defined by $\,a_1\in\left[-\dfrac14,\dfrac14\right]\,$ and $\;a_{j+1}=a_j^2-\dfrac14\;,\;$ for all $\,j\geq1.$

First of all, I will prove by induction that

$\big|a_n\big|\leqslant\dfrac14\qquad\forall\,n\in\mathbb N\;.\qquad\color{blue}{(1)}$

If $\;n=1\;,\;$ then $\;\big|a_n\big|=\big|a_1\big|\leqslant\dfrac14\;,\;$ indeed $\;a_1\in\left[-\dfrac14,\dfrac14\right].$

If $\;n\geqslant2\;,\;$ by supposing that $\;\big|a_{n-1}\big|\leqslant\dfrac14\;,\;$ it follows that

$-\dfrac14\leqslant a_{n-1}^2-\dfrac14\leqslant\dfrac1{16}-\dfrac14=-\dfrac3{16}<0<\dfrac14\;,\quad$ hence

$\big|a_n\big|=\left|a_{n-1}^2-\dfrac14\right|\leqslant\dfrac14\;.$

So, by induction, the statement $\;(1)\;$ holds for all $\;n\in\mathbb N\;.$

Now I will prove that

$\big|a_m-a_n\big|\leqslant\dfrac12\big|a_{m-1}-a_{n-1}\big|\qquad\forall\,m,n\in\mathbb N\setminus\left\{1\right\}.\qquad\color{blue}{(2)}$

For any $\;m,n\in\mathbb N\;\land\;m,n\geqslant2\;,\;$ it results that

$\begin{align}
\big|a_m-a_n\big|&=\left|a_{m-1}^2-\frac14-\left(a_{n-1}^2-\frac14\right)\right|=\big|a_{m-1}^2-a_{n-1}^2\big|=\\
&=\big|a_{m-1}+a_{n-1}\big|\!\cdot\!\big|a_{m-1}-a_{n-1}\big|\leqslant\\
&\leqslant\left(\left|a_{m-1}\right|+\left|a_{n-1}\right|\right)\!\cdot\!\big|a_{m-1}-a_{n-1}\big|\underset{\overbrace{\text{by using }(1)}}{\leqslant}\\
&\leqslant\left(\frac14+\frac14\right)\!\cdot\!\big|a_{m-1}-a_{n-1}\big|=\frac12\big|a_{m-1}-a_{n-1}\big|\;.
\end{align}$

It means that the statement $(2)$ holds for all $\;m,n\in\mathbb N\setminus\left\{1\right\}.$

Let $\,\epsilon\,$ be any positive real number $\;(\;\epsilon>0\;)\;$.

Since $\;\lim_\limits{q\to\infty}\left(\dfrac12\right)^{\!q}=0\;,\;$ there exists $\;k\in\mathbb N\;$ such that

$\left(\dfrac12\right)^{\!q}<\epsilon\quad$ for all $\;q\in\mathbb N\;\land\;q>k\;.\quad\color{blue}{(3)}$

Moreover, for all $\;m,n\in\mathbb N\;\land\;m,n>k\;,\;$ by applying $\;(2)\;$ repeatedly $\left(k\;\text{times}\right)$, it results that

$\begin{align}
\big|a_m-a_n\big|&\leqslant\dfrac12\big|a_{m-1}-a_{n-1}\big|\leqslant\left(\dfrac12\right)^{\!2}\,\bigg|a_{m-2}-a_{n-2}\bigg|\leqslant\ldots\leqslant\\
&\leqslant\left(\dfrac12\right)^{\!k}\,\bigg|a_{m-k}-a_{n-k}\bigg|\leqslant\left(\dfrac12\right)^{\!k}\!\bigg(\big|a_{m-k}\big|+\big|a_{n-k}\big|\bigg)\underset{\overbrace{\text{by using }(1)}}{\leqslant}\\
&\leqslant\left(\dfrac12\right)^{\!k}\!\left(\dfrac14+\dfrac14\right)=\left(\dfrac12\right)^{\!k+1}\underset{\overbrace{\text{by using }(3)\text{ with }q=k+1}}{<}\\
&<\epsilon\;.
\end{align}$

So I have proved that

$\forall\;\epsilon>0\;$ there exists $\;k\in\mathbb N\;$ such that for all $\;m,n\in\mathbb N\;\land\;m,n>k\;,\;$ it results that $\;\big|a_m-a_n\big|<\epsilon\;.$

It means that $\,\left\{a_j\right\}_{j\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathbb R\,$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Since the set of real numbers $\;\mathbb R\;$ is a complete metric space with the standard metric $\;d(x,y)=\left|x-y\right|\,,\;$ the Cauchy sequence $\,\left\{a_j\right\}_{j\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathbb R\,$ is convergent.